# How to align text between divs

Tags: css, html, text, alignment

This is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/F6pNm/8/

I need the text to appear on same line as the links. But it keeps using adding a empty line at the right.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I need the text within the div to be centered between the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this:

`#footer {text-align:center;}`

and add

`#flash {display:inline}`  to the 'flash' id

if will work
: http://jsfiddle.net/F6pNm/24/

note: This will also work if you want to center more than one div, just use a `class` instead of an `id` (and `.` instead of `#`) to apply it to multiple divs

Comment: I need to have the text in a One-Line scrolling div, fitting inside both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6pNm/26/ could you help

Comment: you should really ask a separate question, on this website for asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Have `div#flash` float left as well.

Comment: Ok that works, but that div is now left-aligned and I want it be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` for the flash div.  Since you mentioned you want the content centered, add `#footer { text-align: center; }` to your style rules.